Webpack Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join')
I'm working on a legacy MEAN project and i have updated nodejs to version 20 and updated webpack, webpack-command and webpack-cli and node-sass packages, now encountering the above error when running the project with yarn.
below is my webpack config file.
my package.json file
the error I encountering
If anyone could please help, I have spent many hours to get it workaround, now stuck here after doing everything and after updating many packages to latest to get it work on my node version 20.
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

console.log(__dirname);
let currentDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname);

module.exports = (env) => {
  // console.log(process.env);
  // console.log(env.ENV);
  // console.log(env`your text`.ENV == 'dev');
  return {
    mode: env.ENV === "dev" ? "development" : "production",
    entry: {
      loader: path.resolve(currentDirectory + "/loader/loader.ts"),
      loaderForLoad: path.resolve(
        currentDirectory + "/loader/loaderForLoad.ts"
      ),
      "chat-bubble": path.resolve(
        currentDirectory + "/chatbubble/chat-bubble.ts"
      ),
      "auto-message": path.resolve(
        currentDirectory + "/automessage/auto-message.ts"
      ),
      "popup-frame": path.resolve(
        currentDirectory + "/popupFrame/popup-frame.ts"
      )
    },
    output: {
      path: path.join(currentDirectory + "/dist/static/js/"),
      filename: "[name].[hash].js",
      publicPath: function () {
        return (
          (env.ENV == "dev"
            ? "https://dev.beelinks.solutions/cbam/js"
            : "" + "") + "/public/js/"
        );
      }
    },
    // devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map',
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    devtool: env.ENV == "dev" ? "eval-cheap-module-source-map" : undefined,
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          loader: "ts-loader",
          exclude: ["/node_modules/", "/chatwindow/", "/negotiate/"],
          options: {
            // disable type checker - we will use it in fork plugin
            transpileOnly: true
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(s*)css$/,
          use: [
            { loader: "style-loader" },
            { loader: "css-loader" },
            { loader: "sass-loader" }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "file-loader",
              options: {
                name: "[name].[ext]",
                outputPath: "../fonts/",
                publicPath: function (url) {
                  return "/cw/assets/fonts/" + url;
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(wav|mpg|mpeg|mp3)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "file-loader",
              options: {
                name: "[name].[ext]",
                outputPath: "../audio/",
                publicPath: function (url) {
                  return "/public/audio/" + url;
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin([
        "dist/static/js/*.*",
        "dist/static/html/*.*",
        "dist/manifest.json"
      ]),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env": {
          __BIZC_Environment: JSON.stringify(env.ENV)
        }
      }),
      new ManifestPlugin({
        fileName: path.resolve(currentDirectory + "/dist/manifest.json"),
        publicPath: ""
      }),
      new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        hash: false,
        template: path.resolve(
          currentDirectory + "/chatbubble/chat-bubble.html"
        ),
        filename: path.resolve(
          currentDirectory + "/dist/static/html/chat-bubble.html"
        ),
        chunks: ["chat-bubble"],
        excludeChunks: ["loader", "auto-message", "loaderForLoad"],
        inject: "head",
        minify: {
          removeComments: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true
        }
      }),
      // new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
      //     cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
      //         preset: ['default', { discardComments: { removeAll: true } }],
      //     },
      // }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        hash: false,
        template: path.resolve(
          currentDirectory + "/automessage/auto-message.html"
        ),
        filename: path.resolve(
          currentDirectory + "/dist/static/html/auto-message.html"
        ),
        chunks: ["auto-message"],
        excludeChunks: ["loader", "loaderForLoad", "chat-bubble"],
        inject: "head",
        minify: {
          removeComments: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true
        }
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        hash: false,
        template: path.resolve(
          currentDirectory + "/popupFrame/popup-frame.html"
        ),
        filename: path.resolve(
          currentDirectory + "/dist/static/html/popup-frame.html"
        ),
        chunks: ["popup-frame"],
        excludeChunks: [
          "loader",
          "loaderForLoad",
          "chat-bubble",
          "auto-message"
        ],
        inject: "head",
        minify: {
          removeComments: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true
        }
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
          from: path.resolve(currentDirectory + "/error_pages"),
          to: path.resolve(currentDirectory + "/dist/static/error_pages/"),
          force: true
        },
        {
          from: path.resolve(currentDirectory + "/dynamichtml"),
          to: path.resolve(currentDirectory + "/dist/static/dynamichtml/"),
          force: true
        }
        //{ from: path.resolve(currentDirectory + '/chatwindow/dist'), to: path.resolve(currentDirectory + '/dist/static/chatwindow/'), force: true }, // html
        //{ from: path.resolve(currentDirectory + '/css'), to: path.resolve(currentDirectory + '/dist/static/css/'), force: true }, // css
        // { from: path.resolve(currentDirectory + '/dynamichtml'), to: path.resolve(currentDirectory + '/dist/static/assets/dynamichtml/'), force: true },//for js
        // { from: path.resolve(currentDirectory + '/dynamichtml'), to: path.resolve(currentDirectory + '/dist/static/assets/dynamichtml/'), force: true },//for assets
      ]),

      new CopyWebpackPlugin(
        env.ENV == "dev"
          ? [
              {
                from: path.resolve(currentDirectory + "/chatwindow/dist"),
                to: path.resolve(currentDirectory + "/dist/static/cw/"),
                force: true
              }
            ]
          : []
      ),
      new CompressionPlugin({
        algorithm: "gzip",
        test: /\.(js|ttf|eot|svg|gif)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        minRatio: 0.8
      })
    ],
    optimization: {
      minimize: true,
      minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()]
    }
  };
};


Thank you.

That stack dump would be better pasted as text, delimited by triple-back-ticks. That way, others can find it when they search. I also notice that you've used path.resolve in other parts of the code but the error occurs when you use path.join with a similar parameter.

I get it, next time will do that, and I changed path.join to path.resolve but getting the same error, I dunno may be it is related with webpack, as I have updated the packages to latest.
